# .NET Core 7 C# - db context being disposed after successful http PostAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-7.0

Log records are written to a file when user events happen.

However, I am getting an 'object disposed error' when writing a log record after a PostAsync call.The DB context is being disposed of following the call, which is successfully processed with an OK response and valid content for processing.

I have not used any 'usings' which I have seen as a potential issue.

I isolated the issue by adding log record writes around each statement, below is a minimal version of the controller. -103z is successfully written but -104 fails with the db context disposed of issue. Without all these 'write log records' the process works successfully until the final normal log record is written, which fails and is when I started having this issue.

Why is the dbcontext disposed? The commented-out lines are to test the solution using WebClient, which although obsolete, works fine.

Start with Core Web App (MVC)

FlightFollowController with the issue:

```
using DBContext_test.DBContext;
using DBContext_test.Models;

namespace DBContext_test.Controllers
{
public class FlightFollowController : BaseController
{
    public FlightFollowController(GliderFFContext db) : base(db)
    {
    }

    public async void StartFlightFollowing()
    {
        string url = "https://catfact.ninja/fact";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        //var client = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            await WriteLogRecord(88, "Dispose find check -103z");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            //string response = client.DownloadString(url);
            await WriteLogRecord(88, "Dispose find check -104"); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

    public Task WriteLogRecord(int recType, string summary)
    {
        FFActionLogs logEntry = new FFActionLogs();
        logEntry.ActionTime = DateTime.Now;
        logEntry.RecordType = recType;
        logEntry.Summary = summary;
        _db.FFActionLogs.Add(logEntry);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
}
```

BaseController is where the DB context is set up.

```
using DBContext_test.DBContext;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DBContext_test.Controllers
{
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public GliderFFContext _db;

    public BaseController(GliderFFContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
}
```

DBContext:

```
using DBContext_test.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DBContext_test.DBContext
{
public class GliderFFContext: DbContext
{
    public GliderFFContext(DbContextOptions<GliderFFContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<FFActionLogs> FFActionLogs { get; set; }
}
}
```

Program.cs

```
using DBContext_test.DBContext;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});  

  builder.Services.AddDbContext<GliderFFContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("GliderFF") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'GliderFF' not found.")));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
// The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

appsettings.json - obviously a connection to a db is required, I have ** the real connection details

```
{
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
}
},
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
"GliderFF": "Server=****;Database=DBContextTest;user id=****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
}
}
```

A change is required to the Home controller to fire the 'StartFlightFollowing()'

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
<h1 class="display-4">Click for db test</h1>
@Html.ActionLink("Run test", "StartFlightFollowing", "FlightFollow", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
 </div>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Why aren't you using `async`?

Comment: Where is `_db` defined and populated?

Comment: @Dai I am using async, aren't I? HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

Comment: Your `public Task WriteLogRecord` method should be async, so you can do `await _db.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: @StephenCleary I built a minimal app and have reproduced the issue. I just posted the issue to the MS community. How do I make the minimal app available to view?

Comment: @Brian.S: If it is truly minimal, it can just be included in your question.

Comment: @StephenCleary Edited question for entire minimal solution. You need to set up a link to a db to actually run it.

Answer (score 2):

> public async void StartFlightFollowing()

This is your problem. Change `async void` to `async Task` and you should be fine.

As a general rule, [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#avoid-async-void). The main problem with `async void` is that the caller doesn't know when the asynchronous operation completes[*]. In this case, ASP.NET sees your controller action return when it hits that first `await`, so it figures it's done, and proceeds to tear down the request context, disposing all the scoped instances including your db context. By returning `Task`, ASP.NET knows to keep the request context (and scoped instances) alive until the `Task` completes at the end of your action method.

[*] - Technically, it's *possible* for some callers to detect when `async void` methods complete. In fact, ASP.NET pre-Core actually did this. But it was pretty hacky and questionable, and was removed in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Great. It worked, thanks for putting the effort in to help. I am finding several issues like this, where there are very small changes in the new NET Core and C# which weren't an issue before. I accept that things need to be tightened up, but it is frustrating. I did actually make some changes from void to Task elsewhere in the code, but didn't try that here. Also, the error generated was not helpful in finding the problem.